# What kind of plug does this machine take?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power

I was in my attic and I found what seems to be a light projector, it appears to have no power as the on/off switch won't work, so I think it may be out of battery, the only thing I found related to battery was that plug on that back, I searched all around my house but didn't find any plug that would work with it.
Could you guys help me find out what plug it is so I can purchase one at my local store?

(European by the way, I don't know if that helps anything)

Images of the projector: 
[image]

[image]

[image]

After brute forcing the fan open, this is how it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Might be dc 6v but that’s a wag...

Comment: That plug looks like a standard "DC barrel jack" but there's nothing standard about them. They are used for a variety of voltages and polarities, and aren't even strictly DC. If you know the type, arrangement, and number of batteries the device takes, that gets you closer.

Comment: @JYelton is there any way of finding out just by the "barrel jack"? these screws are kinda loose but won't come out, so I can't open the thing :(

Comment: No, the jack is extremely common in many lower-wattage devices. There are 2.1mm and 2.5mm variants (and others) but this tells you nothing about the circuit to which it is attached. You will need to find documentation or open the device. Unless you're willing to experiment and potentially damage it by guessing. That said, this site is for electronics engineering questions rather than device usage or repair questions, so this question may be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The barrel jack mates with a wire from a "wall wart" wall  plug adapter most likely, and most likely it supplies DC voltage.

If you can read the voltage on the cooling fan label it's a fair guess that the input voltage matches that. Probably something like 12VDC.

[image]

Center pin is usually positive, but again no guarantees (wrong polarity or voltage will or can damage it). You can open it up and trace the connections- if the fan goes directly through a switch to the input power that will give you the voltage and polarity.

Current requirement is a complete guess but it could be measured.

To spec a replacement wall wart you need the connector, polarity, voltage, and current requirement (at a minimum).

Comment: the screws around don't work so I kinda brute forced the fan open, it says DC12, I assume that is it? here's a photo of how the fan looks: https://imgur.com/a/Rl0cJrS

Comment: Yes, it says 12VDC.